# ANTLR4: Need assistance with conditional handling of whitespace within grammar files

Tags: parsing, syntax, whitespace, antlr4, grammar

I am new to ANTLR, but have composed a largely-functional (4.13.0) parser/lexer for a particular access control syntax.

## Introduction

Just for context, the end goal for this grammar implementation is to facilitate the parsing of compliant textual expressions into object-based representations that can be analyzed programmatically by the admin.

## Setup/Environment

For the moment, my efforts are confined to the use of **`java`** on the (Ubuntu) command-line via the **`antlr4`** bash alias, as described on the [ANTLR site](https://www.antlr.org/).

I am conducting tests using the attached grammar files and am "piping" test input to **`grun`** using **`echo`** and **`cat`**. Essentially I am doing it like the following example (and other values reside within the parser grammar file attached):

```
$ antlr4 ACI*.g4 ; javac *.java
$ echo -n '(ssf>="128")' | grun ACI bindSecurityStrengthFactor -tree -trace
<desirable result output>
```

This solution as a whole is very (VERY) close to what I want. Considering I only started learning ANTLR about three days ago, I am very pleased with the result. The things that work are absolutely rock-solid.

There is one fairly important problem, however.

## Whitespace

With the understanding that I have read (what I believe to be) the relevant sections of the PDF titled "**The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference - By Terence Parr**", and with the understanding that I have read many similar threads on this very forum, I find myself unable to devise a reliable solution for the problem at hand.

Overall, whitespace should be largely forgiven within the terms of this parser. Naturally, there are a few exceptions (e.g.: *keywords* shall not possess spaces), though several "value definitions" do need to allow spaces, such as `distinguishedName`, `aVAOrRDN` and `attributeTypeOrValue` (when used in the context of a value). The good news is that (value-wise) I have achieved what I need.  For example, I can specify a DN such as:

`ldap:///cn=Courtney Tolana,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`

... and it works as expected (the above given name and surname -- including the space -- are preserved as a so-called "common name" string value).

## Problem

What is NOT working is everywhere that spaces should not/do not matter. Specifically, I am referring to the following:

```
     this too
     v
key = "value"
   ^
   this
```

A user should be able to sloppily specify `key="value"`, `key = "value"` and any other permutation involving inter-field whitespace. And yet, not removing the whitespace beforehand shall end in failure:

```
$ echo -n 'userdn = "ldap:///uid=Courtney Tolana,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"' | grun ACI bindUserDN -tree
```

... produces:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'userdn ' expecting {'(', 'userdn'}
(bindUserDN userdn  =   " ldap:/// uid = Courtney Tolana , ou = People , dc = example , dc = com ")
```

When proactively cleaning-up said whitespace, it's smooth as glass:

```
$ echo -n 'userdn="ldap:///uid=Courtney Tolana,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"' | grun ACI  bindUserDN -tree
```

... produces:

```
(bindUserDN userdn (equalTo =) (distinguishedNames " (distinguishedName ldap:/// (aVAOrRDN (attributeTypeOrValue uid) (attributeComparisonOperator (equalTo =)) (attributeTypeOrValue Courtney Tolana)) , (aVAOrRDN (attributeTypeOrValue ou) (attributeComparisonOperator (equalTo =)) (attributeTypeOrValue People)) , (aVAOrRDN (attributeTypeOrValue dc) (attributeComparisonOperator (equalTo =)) (attributeTypeOrValue example)) , (aVAOrRDN (attributeTypeOrValue dc) (attributeComparisonOperator (equalTo =)) (attributeTypeOrValue com))) "))
```

## Remedial Attempts

Naturally, it occurred to me that simple placement of the WHSP redirection could be the culprit.

```
// this.
WHITESPACE
  : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
  ;
```

So I moved it around, first at the beginning of the file, then at the end. It seems like every suggestion I tried either made no perceptible difference OR caused previously-working rules to suddenly break.

I also tried switching to a default channel instead of "skip" (e.g.: `channel(HIDDEN);`) but this did not help.

I've also experimented with polluting the grammar with optional whitespace expressions between known component tokens (e.g.: `KEYWORD WHSP? OPERATOR ...`), and while this worked *some of the time*, it did not offer a global solution (plus its just ugly, and I'm kind of glad it didn't work).

It seems each time I try to approach this specific problem (admittedly sometimes in desperation), I end up reversing tons of progress made previously because I unwittingly introduced *new problems* while trying some of the solutions I am able to glean. I think my wheels are spinning in the mud, and I would just love to know what is going on so I can finish this project off. I'm so close!

## Parser Grammar

Here is the parser grammar, from which I had to remove many useful comments thanks to SO's character limit and lack of file upload.

```
// ACIv3 Parser Grammar - work in progress

parser grammar ACIParser;
options { tokenVocab=ACILexer; }
parse
  : instruction EOF
  ;

instruction
  : targetRules LPAREN ANCHOR DQUOTE attributeTypeOrValue DQUOTE WHSP*? SEMI WHSP*? permissionBindRules WHSP? RPAREN # aci
  ;

// permissionBindRules describes one (1) or more permissionBindRule
// values. Values of this kind appear within the top-level of an ACI.
permissionBindRules
  : permissionBindRule*     # permission_bind_rules
  ;

// permissionBindRule describes a permission and Bind Rule pair.
// Values of this kind appear within permissionBindRules values.
permissionBindRule
  : permission bindRule WHSP? SEMI WHSP?    # permission_and_bind_rule_pair
  ;

// permission describes a complete permissive statement for an ACI, which
// may either grant or deny certain privileges.
//
// e.g.: allow(read,search,compare)
permission
  : permissionDisposition WHSP*? LPAREN ( WHSP*? accessPrivileges ( COMMA accessPrivileges WHSP*?)* ) WHSP*? RPAREN # permission_expression
  ;

// permissionDisposition describes the disposition of a given ACI permission
// statement, which may be either 'allow' or 'deny'.
permissionDisposition
  : ALLOW_ACCESS    # allow_access
  | DENY_ACCESS     # deny_access
  ;

accessPrivileges
  : SEARCH_PRIVILEGE    # search_privilege
  | READ_PRIVILEGE  # read_privilege
  | COMPARE_PRIVILEGE   # compare_privilege
  | ADD_PRIVILEGE   # add_privilege
  | DELETE_PRIVILEGE    # delete_privilege
  | SELFWRITE_PRIVILEGE # selfwrite_privilege
  | PROXY_PRIVILEGE # proxy_privilege
  | IMPORT_PRIVILEGE    # import_privilege
  | EXPORT_PRIVILEGE    # export_privilege
  | ALL_PRIVILEGES  # all_privileges
  ;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Begin TARGET RULES

// targetRules defines a sequence of zero (0) or more
// targetRule instances; use of Target Rules is optional
// in ACIs, however Target Rule statements are *ALWAYS*
// parenthetical, unlike Bind Rules which may be either.
targetRules
  : targetRule*              # target_rules
  ;

// targetRule defines any one (1) of nine (9) possible
// Target Rule types.
targetRule
  : targetControl       # rule_is_targetcontrol
  | targetExtendedOperation # rule_is_extop
  | targetFilter        # rule_is_targetfilter
  | targetAttrFilters       # rule_is_targattrfilters
  | targetScope         # rule_is_targetscope
  | targetAttributes        # rule_is_targetattr
  | target          # rule_is_target
  | targetTo            # rule_is_target_to
  | targetFrom          # rule_is_target_from
  ;

target
  : LPAREN TARGET (equalTo|notEqualTo) distinguishedNames RPAREN                        # target_dn_rule
  ;

targetTo
  : LPAREN TARGET_TO (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE distinguishedName DQUOTE RPAREN                # target_to_rule
  ;

targetFrom
  : LPAREN TARGET_FROM (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE distinguishedName DQUOTE RPAREN              # target_from_rule
  ;

targetFilter
  : LPAREN TARGET_FILTER (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE lDAPFilter DQUOTE RPAREN                   # targetfilter_rule
  ;

targetAttrFilters
  : LPAREN TARGET_ATTR_FILTERS equalTo DQUOTE targetAttrFiltersValue DQUOTE RPAREN              # targattrfilters_rule
  ;

targetScope
  : LPAREN TARGET_SCOPE equalTo DQUOTE targetSearchScopes DQUOTE RPAREN                 # targetscope_rule
  ;

targetAttributes
  : LPAREN TARGET_ATTR (equalTo|notEqualTo) targetedAttributes RPAREN                   # targetattr_rule
  ;

targetControl
  : LPAREN TARGET_CONTROL (equalTo|notEqualTo) objectIdentifiers RPAREN                 # targetcontrol_rule
  ;

targetExtendedOperation
  : LPAREN TARGET_EXTENDED_OPERATION (equalTo|notEqualTo) objectIdentifiers RPAREN          # targetextop_rule
  ;

targetSearchScopes
  : BASE_OBJECT_SCOPE       # base_object_targetscope
  | ONE_LEVEL_TARGET_SCOPE      # one_level_targetscope
  | SUB_TREE_TARGET_SCOPE   # sub_tree_targetscope
  | SUBORDINATE_TARGET_SCOPE    # subordinate_targetscope
  ;

objectIdentifiers
  : DQUOTE ( objectIdentifier ( oRDelimiter objectIdentifier )* ) DQUOTE                        # quoted_object_identifier_list
  | ( DQUOTE objectIdentifier DQUOTE ( oRDelimiter (DQUOTE objectIdentifier DQUOTE) )* )        # list_of_quoted_object_identifiers
  ;

targetedAttributes
  : DQUOTE ( attributeTypeOrValue ( oRDelimiter attributeTypeOrValue )* ) DQUOTE                # quoted_targeted_attributes_list
  | ( DQUOTE attributeTypeOrValue DQUOTE ( oRDelimiter (DQUOTE attributeTypeOrValue DQUOTE) )* )    # list_of_quoted_attributes
  | DQUOTE STAR DQUOTE                                          # all_attributes
  ;

// e.g.: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18
objectIdentifier
  : ( numberForm ( DOT numberForm )+ )                          # object_identifier
  ;

numberForm
  : INT                                                                 # number_form
  ;

// Note this is behaving a little quirky, not sure I've got it nailed down yet ;/
targetAttrFiltersValue
  : attributeFilters           # attribute_filters_sets
  | attributeFilterSet         # attribute_filters_set
  | attributeFilter            # attribute_filter_single
  ;

attributeFilters
  : attributeFilterSet (COMMA|SEMI) attributeFilterSet     # attribute_filters
  ;

attributeFilterSet
  : attributeFilterOperation ( attributeFilter ( aNDDelimiter attributeFilter )* )? # attribute_filter_set
  ;

attributeFilterOperation
  : ADD_PRIVILEGE equalTo   # add_filter_operation
  | DELETE_PRIVILEGE equalTo    # delete_filter_operation
  ;

attributeFilter
  : attributeTypeOrValue COLON lDAPFilter   # attribute_filter
  ;

// Bind Rule Boolean statements
//
// e.g.:
//  - (timeofday >= "1730" AND timeofday < "2400")
//  - authmethod = "SASL"
//
bindRule
  : bindRuleExpr                                                        # bind_rule
  | bindRuleExprParen ((BOOLEAN_AND|BOOLEAN_OR|BOOLEAN_NOT) bindRuleExprParen)* # parenthetical_bind_rule
  ;

// Parenthetical Bind Rule expressions
bindRuleExprParen
  : LPAREN bindRuleExpr ((BOOLEAN_AND|BOOLEAN_OR|BOOLEAN_NOT) bindRuleExpr)* RPAREN # parenthetical_bind_rule_req_bool_op
  | <assoc=right> BOOLEAN_NOT bindRuleExpr                      # negated_bind_rule_expression
  | LPAREN bindRuleExpr RPAREN                                                  # parenthetical_bind_rule_expression
  | bindRuleExpr                                                                # bind_rule_expression_recursion
  ;

// bindRuleExpr contains a single Bind Rule
//
// e.g.: ssf >= "128"
bindRuleExpr
  : LPAREN bindRuleExpr RPAREN   # rule_is_parenthetical
  | bindUserDN                   # rule_is_userdn
  | bindUserAttr                 # rule_is_userattr
  | bindGroupDN                  # rule_is_groupdn
  | bindGroupAttr                # rule_is_groupattr
  | bindRoleDN                   # rule_is_roledn
  | bindDNS                      # rule_is_dns
  | bindIP                       # rule_is_ip
  | bindTimeOfDay                # rule_is_timeofday
  | bindDayOfWeek                # rule_is_dayofweek
  | bindSecurityStrengthFactor   # rule_is_ssf
  | bindAuthMethod               # rule_is_authmethod
  ;

// 'dayofweek' Bind Rule syntax
//
// e.g.: dayofweek="Mon,Tues,Fri"
bindDayOfWeek
  : LPAREN bindDayOfWeek RPAREN                                         # parenthetical_dayofweek_bind_rule
  | BIND_DAY_OF_WEEK (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE ( doW ( COMMA doW )* ) DQUOTE  # dayofweek_bind_rule
  ;

doW
  : SUNDAY  # Sun
  | MONDAY  # Mon
  | TUESDAY # Tues
  | WEDNESDAY   # Wed
  | THURSDAY    # Thur
  | FRIDAY  # Fri
  | SATURDAY    # Sat
  ;

// e.g.: authmethod != "none"
bindAuthMethod
  : LPAREN bindAuthMethod RPAREN                                            # parentheticalAuthenticationMethod
  | BIND_AUTH_METHOD (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE authenticationMethods DQUOTE   # authentication_method
  ;

authenticationMethods
  : ANONYMOUS   # none
  | SIMPLE  # simple
  | SSL     # ssl
  | SASL    # sasl
  ;

// e.g.: userdn="ldap:///uid=someone,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
bindUserDN
  : LPAREN bindUserDN RPAREN                                # parenthetical_bind_userdn 
  | BIND_USER_DN (equalTo|notEqualTo) WHSP? (distinguishedNames|DQUOTE lDAPURI DQUOTE)  # bind_userdn
  ;

// e.g.: roledn="ldap:///uid=someone,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
bindRoleDN
  : LPAREN bindRoleDN RPAREN                    # parenthetical_bind_roledn
  | BIND_ROLE_DN (equalTo|notEqualTo) distinguishedNames    # bind_roledn
  ;

// e.g.: groupdn="ldap:///cn=X.500 Administrators,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com"
bindGroupDN
  : LPAREN bindGroupDN RPAREN                                   # parenthetical_bind_groupdn
  | BIND_GROUP_DN (equalTo|notEqualTo) (distinguishedNames|DQUOTE lDAPURI DQUOTE)   # bind_groupdn
  ;

// e.g.: userattr="owner#USERDN"
bindUserAttr
  : LPAREN bindUserAttr RPAREN                                  # parenthetical_bind_userattr
  | BIND_USER_ATTR (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE (attributeBindTypeOrValue|inheritance) DQUOTE  # bind_userattr
  ;

// e.g.: groupattr="manager#LDAPURL"
bindGroupAttr
  : LPAREN bindGroupAttr RPAREN                                             # parenthetical_bind_groupattr
  | BIND_GROUP_ATTR (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE (attributeBindTypeOrValue|inheritance) DQUOTE   # bind_groupattr
  ;

// e.g.: ssf != "0"
bindSecurityStrengthFactor
  : LPAREN bindSecurityStrengthFactor RPAREN                                                # parenthetical_ssf
  | BIND_SSF (equalTo|notEqualTo|greaterThan|greaterThanOrEqual|lessThan|lessThanOrEqual) DQUOTE INT DQUOTE # bind_ssf
  ;

// e.g.: (timeofday >= "1730" AND timeofday < "2400")
bindTimeOfDay
  : LPAREN bindTimeOfDay RPAREN                                             # parenthetical_bind_timeofday
  | BIND_TIME_OF_DAY (equalTo|notEqualTo|greaterThan|greaterThanOrEqual|lessThan|lessThanOrEqual) DQUOTE INT DQUOTE # bind_timeofday
  ;

// 'ip' Bind Rule syntax
//
// e.g.: ip = "192.168.0,12.3.45.*,10.0.0.0/8"
bindIP
  : LPAREN bindIP RPAREN                                # parenthetical_bind_ip
  | BIND_IP (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE iPAddresses DQUOTE  # bind_ip
  ;

// e.g.: dns = "www.example.com"
bindDNS
  : LPAREN bindDNS RPAREN                                   # parenthetical_bind_dns
  | BIND_DNS (equalTo|notEqualTo) DQUOTE fQDN DQUOTE            # dns_bind_rule
  ;

// e.g.: '192.168.0,12.3.45.*,10.0.0.0/8'
iPAddresses
  : ( iPAddress ( COMMA iPAddress )* )+?                    # ips
  ;

// iPAddress describes any single IPv4 or IPv6 address, and may include
// STAR for octet wildcard statements.
iPAddress
  : iPv4Address                             # ipv4_address
  | iPv6Address                             # ipv6_address
  ;

// iPv4Address describes a single IPv4 address, which may include a
// STAR for octet wildcard statements.
//
// e.g.: '192.168.*'
iPv4Address
  : ( INT ( DOT (INT|STAR)* ) )                     # ipv4
  ;

// iPv6Address describes a single IPv6 address, which may include a
// STAR for octet wildcard statements.
//
// e.g.: '2001:470:dead:beef::'
iPv6Address
  : ( attributeTypeOrValue ( COLON attributeTypeOrValue )+ COLON? ) # ipv6
  ;

// fQDN describes a single fully-qualified domain name, which may 
// include a STAR for label wildcard statements.
//
// e.g.: 'www.example.com' or '*.example.com'
fQDN
  : ( attributeTypeOrValue ( DOT attributeTypeOrValue )+ )      # fqdn
  ;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Begin LDAP related rules

lDAPURI
  : distinguishedName uRIAttributeList uRISearchScopes uRISearchFilter  # fully_qualified_ldapuri
  | distinguishedName QMARK attributeBindTypeOrValue            # fully_qualified_ldapuri_attr_bindtype_or_value
  ;

uRISearchFilter
  : QMARK lDAPFilter                                                 # uriSearchFilter
  ;

uRISearchScopes
  : QMARK (BASE_OBJECT_SCOPE|ONE_LEVEL_SCOPE|SUB_TREE_SCOPE)?        # uriSearchScopes
  ;

uRIAttributeList
  : QMARK ( attributeTypeOrValue ( COMMA attributeTypeOrValue )* )?  # uriAttributeList
  ;

distinguishedNames
  : DQUOTE ( distinguishedName ( oRDelimiter distinguishedName )* ) DQUOTE                  # quoted_distinguished_name_list
  | ( DQUOTE distinguishedName DQUOTE ( oRDelimiter (DQUOTE distinguishedName DQUOTE) )* )  # list_of_quoted_distinguished_names
  ;

// distinguishedName is a sequence of aVAOrRDN values. Macro
// variable declarations for [$dn], ($dn) and ($attr.<atname>)
// are supported.
//
// e.g.: "ldap:///uid=courtney,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
distinguishedName
  : ( LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME aVAOrRDN ( COMMA (aVAOrRDN|rDNMacros) )* )  # dn
  | LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME ANYONE                        # anonymous_dn_alias
  | LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME ALL_USERS                     # any_user_dn_alias
  | LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME SELF                      # self_dn_alias
  | LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME PARENT                        # parent_dn_alias
  ;

// rDNMacros contains macro variables for DSA interpolation. 
// e.g.: "ldap:///uid=courtney,($attr.ou),ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
rDNMacros
  : RDN_MACROS                              # rdn_macro
  ;

// e.g.: "(&(objectClass=employee)(terminated=FALSE))"
lDAPFilter
  : LPAREN lDAPFilterExpr RPAREN        # parenthetical_filter_expression
  | lDAPFilterExpr*                     # filter_expressions
  ;

lDAPFilterExpr
  : (LPAREN (FILTER_AND|FILTER_OR|FILTER_NOT)? lDAPFilterExpr RPAREN)+?    # parenthetical_filter_expression_opt_bool
  | <assoc=right> FILTER_NOT lDAPFilterExpr                            # not_filter_expression
  | aVAOrRDN                                                   # ava_expression
  ;

// This is an absolutely critical parser component.
aVAOrRDN
  : LPAREN attributeTypeOrValue attributeComparisonOperator attributeTypeOrValue RPAREN # parenthetical_ava_or_rdn
  | attributeTypeOrValue attributeComparisonOperator attributeTypeOrValue       # ava_or_rdn
  ;

// e.g.: 'parent[0,1,3].owner#USERDN'
inheritance
  : ( PARENT inheritanceLevels DOT attributeBindTypeOrValue )       # inheritance_expression
  ;

inheritanceLevels
  : LBRAK ( INT ( COMMA INT )* )+? RBRAK    # inheritance_levels
  ;

// e.g.: 'manager#GROUPDN' or 'nickname#squatcobbler'
attributeBindTypeOrValue
  : attributeTypeOrValue HASH (bindTypes|attributeTypeOrValue)      # attr_bind_type_or_value
  ;

bindTypes
  : BINDTYPE_USER_DN    # USERDN
  | BINDTYPE_GROUP_DN   # GROUPDN
  | BINDTYPE_ROLE_DN    # ROLEDN
  | BINDTYPE_SELF_DN    # SELFDN
  | BINDTYPE_LDAP_URL   # LDAPURL
  ;

// See the lexer KEY_OR_VALUE definition for additional notes
// on the topic of this value.
attributeTypeOrValue
  : KEY_OR_VALUE    # key_or_value
  | STAR        # presence_key_or_value
  ;

// attributeComparisonOperator describes one (1) of eight (8)
// possible comparison operators to be used in LDAP AVAs.
//
// Note that gt/lt are not valid operators for LDAP AVAs, and
// thus they are not listed here. Only ge/le are available for
// (numerical) ordering matches.
attributeComparisonOperator
  : equalTo     # equal_to
  | greaterThanOrEqual  # greater_than_or_equal
  | lessThanOrEqual # less_than_or_equal
  | approximate     # approx
  | extensibleRule  # extensible_rule
  | extensibleRuleDN    # extensible_rule_with_dn
  | extensibleRuleAttr  # extensible_rule_with_attrs
  | extensibleRuleDNOID # extensible_rule_with_dn_oid
  ;

equalTo             : EQ;
notEqualTo          : NE;
greaterThan         : GT;
lessThan            : LT;
greaterThanOrEqual      : GE;
lessThanOrEqual         : LE;
approximate         : APX;
extensibleRule          : COLON;
extensibleRuleDNOID     : EXO;
extensibleRuleDN        : EXD;
extensibleRuleAttr      : EXA;
oRDelimiter         : SYMBOLIC_OR;
aNDDelimiter            : SYMBOLIC_AND;
```

## Lexer Grammar

```
// ACIv3 Lexer Grammar - work in progress

lexer grammar ACILexer;

WHSP: ' '+?;
QMARK: '?';
DQUOTE: '"';
LBRAK: '[';
LPAREN: '(';
RBRAK: ']';
RPAREN: ')';
DOT: '.';
COLON: ':';
TILDE: '~';
EQ: '=';
NE: BANG EQ;
GT: '>';
LT: '<';
APX: TILDE EQ;
GE: GT EQ;
LE: LT EQ;
EXA: COLON EQ;
EXO: COLON 'dn' COLON;
EXD: COLON 'dn' COLON EQ;
HASH: '#';

// Symbolic ANDs (&&) are used as delimiter literals within
// ANDed attributeFilterSet instances.
SYMBOLIC_AND: AMPERSAND AMPERSAND;

fragment AMPERSAND: '&';

// Symbolic ORs (||) are used as delimiter literals within
// ORed lists of attributeTypes, objectIdentifiers and 
// distinguishedNames.
SYMBOLIC_OR: PIPE PIPE;

fragment PIPE: '|';
fragment BANG: '!';

FILTER_AND: AMPERSAND;
FILTER_OR: PIPE;
FILTER_NOT: BANG;
FILTER_OPERATOR
  : FILTER_AND
  | FILTER_OR
  | FILTER_NOT
  ;

COMMA: ',';
SEMI: ';';
STAR: '*';

LOCAL_LDAP_SCHEME: 'ldap:///';
PARENT
  : [Pp][Aa][Rr][Ee][Nn][Tt]
  ;
ANYONE
  : [Aa][Nn][Yy][Oo][Nn][Ee]
  ;

ALL_USERS
  : [Aa][Ll][Ll]
  ;

SELF
  : [Ss][Ee][Ll][Ff]
  ;

ANCHOR
  : 'version 3.0; acl '
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Day Of Week components

// Sunday is day one (1) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
SUNDAY
  : [Ss][Uu][Nn]
  ;

// Monday is day two (2) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
MONDAY
  : [Mm][Oo][Nn]
  ;

// Tuesday is day three (3) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
TUESDAY
  : [Tt][Uu][Ee][Ss]
  ;

// Wednesday is day four (4) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules
WEDNESDAY
  : [Ww][Ee][Dd]
  ;

// Thursday is day five (5) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
THURSDAY
  : [Tt][Hh][Uu][Rr]
  ;

// Friday is day six (6) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
FRIDAY
  : [Ff][Rr][Ii]
  ;

// Saturday is day seven (7) and is used within 'dayofweek' Bind Rules.
SATURDAY
  : [Ss][Aa][Tt]
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Authentication Method string literals

// 'none' describes an ANONYMOUS LDAP bind.
ANONYMOUS
  : [Nn][Oo][Nn][Ee]
  ;

// 'simple' describes an authenticated LDAP bind
// using weak authentication (DN + clear-text).
SIMPLE
  : [Ss][Ii][Mm][Pp][Ll][Ee]
  ;

// 'ssl' describes an authenticated LDAP bind 
// using weak authentication (DN + clear-text)
// using TLS confidentiality.
SSL
  : [Ss][Ss][Ll]
  ;

// 'sasl' describes an authenticated LDAP bind
// using strong authentication (TLS mutual auth,
// Kerberos, et al) and (almost certainly) using
// TLS confidentiality.
SASL
  : [Ss][Aa][Ss][Ll]
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Target Rule keywords

// 'target' Target Rule keyword
TARGET
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt]
  ;

// 'target_to' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_TO
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt] '_' [Tt][Oo]
  ;

// 'target_from' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_FROM
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt] '_' [Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm]
  ;

// 'targetscope' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_SCOPE
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt][Ss][Cc][Oo][Pp][Ee]
  ;

// 'targetattr' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_ATTR
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt][Aa][Tt][Tt][Rr]
  ;

// 'targetfilter' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_FILTER
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt][Ff][Ii][Ll][Tt][Ee][Rr]
  ;

// 'targattrfilters' Target Rule keyword
// NOTE: Yes, it (targ) is the correct Target keyword
// prefix, unlike most others.
TARGET_ATTR_FILTERS
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Aa][Tt][Tt][Rr][Ff][Ii][Ll][Tt][Ee][Rr][Ss]
  ;

// 'targetcontrol' Target Rule keyword
TARGET_CONTROL
  : [Tt][Aa][Rr][Gg][Ee][Tt][Cc][Oo][Nn][Tt][Rr][Oo][Ll]
  ;

// 'extop' keyword
TARGET_EXTENDED_OPERATION
  : [Ee][Xx][Tt][Oo][Pp]
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Bind Rule keywords

// 'userdn' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_USER_DN
  : 'userdn'
  ;

// 'groupdn' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_GROUP_DN
  : 'groupdn'
  ;

// 'roledn' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_ROLE_DN
  : 'roledn'
  ;

// 'userattr' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_USER_ATTR
  : 'userattr'
  ;

// 'groupattr' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_GROUP_ATTR
  : 'groupattr'
  ;

// 'ssf' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_SSF
  : 'ssf'
  ;

// 'dns' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_DNS
  : 'dns'
  ;

// 'ip' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_IP
  : 'ip'
  ;

// 'authmethod' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_AUTH_METHOD
  : 'authmethod'
  ;

// 'timeofday' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_TIME_OF_DAY
  : 'timeofday'
  ;

// 'dayofweek' Bind Rule keyword
BIND_DAY_OF_WEEK
  : 'dayofweek'
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Bind Type keywords

// USERDN string literal is used within 'userattr' and 'groupattr'
// Bind Rule statements.
BINDTYPE_USER_DN
  : 'USERDN'
  ;

// GROUPDN string literal is used within 'userattr' and 'groupattr'
// Bind Rule statements.
BINDTYPE_GROUP_DN
  : 'GROUPDN'
  ;

// ROLEDN string literal is used within 'userattr' and 'groupattr'
// Bind Rule statements.
BINDTYPE_ROLE_DN
  : 'ROLEDN'
  ;

// SELFDN string literal is used within 'userattr' and 'groupattr'
// Bind Rule statements.
BINDTYPE_SELF_DN
  : 'SELFDN'
  ;

// LDAPURL string literal is used within 'userattr' and 'groupattr'
// Bind Rule statements.
BINDTYPE_LDAP_URL
  : 'LDAPURL'
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// LDAP and Target Rule Search Scopes

// BASE is the same for 'targetscope' Target Rules as for lDAPURI
// search parameters and is used the same in either scenario.
BASE_OBJECT_SCOPE
  : [Bb][Aa][Ss][Ee]
  ;

// This is used exclusively within LDAP Search Parameter statements,
// such as those that appear within an lDAPURI. This is not used
// within 'targetscope' Target Rules.
ONE_LEVEL_SCOPE
  : [Oo][Nn][Ee]
  ;

// This is used exclusively within 'targetscope' Target
// Rules and NOT lDAPURI instances.
ONE_LEVEL_TARGET_SCOPE
  : [Oo][Nn][Ee][Ll][Ee][Vv][Ee][Ll]
  ;

// This is used exclusively within LDAP Search Parameter statements,
// such as those that appear within an lDAPURI. This is not used
// within 'targetscope' Target Rules.
SUB_TREE_SCOPE
  : [Ss][Uu][Bb]
  ;

// This is used exclusively within 'targetscope' Target
// Rules and NOT lDAPURI instances.
SUB_TREE_TARGET_SCOPE
  : [Ss][Uu][Bb][Tt][Rr][Ee][Ee]
  ;

// This is used exclusively within 'targetscope' Target
// Rules and NOT lDAPURI instances.
SUBORDINATE_TARGET_SCOPE
  : [Ss][Uu][Bb][Oo][Rr][Dd][Ii][Nn][Aa][Tt][Ee]
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////
// Permission and Access Rights components

// The disposition of a permission is to grant some level(s)
// of access to the directory.
ALLOW_ACCESS
  : WHSP? [Aa][Ll][Ll][Oo][Ww] WHSP?
  ;

// The disposition of a permission is to deny some level(s)
// of access to the directory.
DENY_ACCESS
  : [Dd][Ee][Nn][Yy]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP search access to the DSA.
SEARCH_PRIVILEGE
  : [Ss][Ee][Aa][Rr][Cc][Hh]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP read access to the DSA.
READ_PRIVILEGE
  : [Rr][Ee][Aa][Dd]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP compare access to the DSA.
COMPARE_PRIVILEGE
  : [Cc][Oo][Mm][Pp][Aa][Rr][Ee]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP entry-creation access to the DSA.
ADD_PRIVILEGE
  : [Aa][Dd][Dd]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP entry-deletion access to the DSA.
DELETE_PRIVILEGE
  : [Dd][Ee][Ll][Ee][Tt][Ee]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP modifications to ones own entry within the DSA.
SELFWRITE_PRIVILEGE
  : [Ss][Ee][Ll][Ff][Ww][Rr][Ii][Tt][Ee]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP remote proxy capabilities within the DSA.
PROXY_PRIVILEGE
  : [Pp][Rr][Oo][Xx][Yy]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP DIT import capabilities within the DSA.
IMPORT_PRIVILEGE
  : [Ii][Mm][Pp][Oo][Rr][Tt]
  ;

// Grant or withhold LDAP DIT export capabilities within the DSA.
EXPORT_PRIVILEGE
  : [Ee][Xx][Pp][Oo][Rr][Tt]
  ;

// Grant or withhold all privileges within the DSA **EXCEPT** for
// proxy privileges.
ALL_PRIVILEGES
  : [Aa][Ll][Ll]
  ;

RDN_MACROS
  : '[$dn]'
  | '($dn)'
  | '($attr' DOT KEY_OR_VALUE ')'
  ;

BOOLEAN_AND
  : [Aa][Nn][Dd]
  ;

BOOLEAN_OR
  : [Oo][Rr]
  ;

BOOLEAN_NOT
  : [Aa][Nn][Dd] ' ' [Nn][Oo][Tt]
  ;

// Whitespace characters are dumped from here on out. I
// know this is supposed to be at the bottom of the lexer
// file (or so I read somewhere), but all hell breaks loose
// when it is :(
WHITESPACE
  : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
  ;

INT
  : [0-9]+
  ;

// KEY_OR_VALUE can more or less be anything, but will be
// verified in the Go visitor.
//
// I REALLY wish I could split this into two (2) lexers that
// WON'T collide, e.g.:
//
// - KEY:   [a-z][a-zA-z0-9\-]* [a-z]*
//
//    ... and ...
//
// - VALUE: ~["\\,.:=!?[\]()#|&<>~\t\r\n]+
//
// ... but I've given up on that for the moment. Every attempt
// to do so wreaks havoc within this otherwise functional setup.
// 
// The (negated!) characters below are specified due to their
// special nature elsewhere in this implementation, i.e.: '&'
// in Boolean lists, and (probably?) shouldn't appear in values
// such as the 'acl' (ACI label), though I'm not 100% certain.
//
// To be honest, I'm quite sure this is NOT an ideal solution
// (likely will barf on certain otherwise harmless characters
// in a value), but it DOES seem to work for the moment ...
KEY_OR_VALUE
  : ~["\\,.:=!?[\]()#|&<>~\t\r\n]+
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From a rather cursory examination of [The ACI spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1277/aci-syntax.html#targeting-a-directory-entry) (This certainly looks like what you're trying to parse; hope I'm right)

- It appears that any places that have significant whitespace are embedded within closing `"` (i.e. they are in strings).
- It also appears that some content within strings treats whitespace as significant (`distinguishedName`) and other contexts may have string content where white space is not significant in parsing the content.

Given that these are context dependent, you won't be able to handle the differences in the Lexer (which maintains no such context).

I believe that leaves you 2 options:

1 - Make whitespace a normal (i.e no `skip` no sending to `HIDDEN` channel), and proceed to cover all the places where whitespace might be allowed.
2 - Treat these "strings" as ACTUAL `STRING`s in you grammar and parse their content in a subsequent phase.

As you've noticed, trying to factor the optional whitepace into your parser rules is "the path to madness".  Not only does it REALLY clutter your parser rules, but you have situations where values that CAN contain whitespaces will come into your parser as multiple tokens (and consist of multiple nodes in the resulting parse tree.)

I would simplify the main grammar significantly, by Tokenizing the Strings as `STRING` tokens.  Then, once you have a parse tree, and know which type of string you should have (depending upon it's context), parse the content of the string with a grammar specific to it's content (ex: [distinguished name according to RFC 2253](https://Note%20-%20The%20DN%20of%20the%20entry%20must%20be%20a%20distinguished%20name%20in%20string%20representation%20(defined%20in%20RFC%202253).)). (NOTE: Pretty sure this would eliminate the need for the `KEY_OR_VALUE` Lexer rule which, as written, will probably be the source of a great deal of pain)

A fairly simple example of how this starts to simplify things:

```
bindDayOfWeek
    : LPAREN bindDayOfWeek RPAREN # parenthetical_dayofweek_bind_rule
    | BIND_DAY_OF_WEEK (equalTo | notEqualTo) DQUOTE (
        doW ( COMMA doW)*
    ) DQUOTE # dayofweek_bind_rule
    ;

doW
    : SUNDAY    # Sun
    | MONDAY    # Mon
    | TUESDAY   # Tues
    | WEDNESDAY # Wed
    | THURSDAY  # Thur
    | FRIDAY    # Fri
    | SATURDAY  # Sat
    ;
```

By changing the bindDayOfWeek rule to:

```
bindDayOfWeek
    : LPAREN bindDayOfWeek RPAREN # parenthetical_dayofweek_bind_rule
    | BIND_DAY_OF_WEEK (equalTo | notEqualTo) STRING # dayofweek_bind_rule
    ;
```

you'll eliminate the need for the `doW` rule as well as the `SUNDAY`, `MONDAY`,  `TUESDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, `THURSDAY,` FRIDAY`, and` SATURDAY` Lexer rules.  You'll just have a string that you will validate has a comma separated list of these values in your parse tree.  In this case, it's probably not even justified to have a full grammar for this string content and it's easy to verify in semantic processing. (Bonus... You'll be able to provide a much better error message than you'd likely get from ANTLR by trying to put everything in the grammar itself)

Effectively, you're parsing the top level of your document, but saying that every string is separate content, that has it's only parsing rules that you can identify by it's place in your parse tree.

---

Something I noticed while looking at your grammar:

```
attributeFilter
  : attributeTypeOrValue COLON lDAPFilter   # attribute_filter
  ;
```

The `# someID` syntax is only of any value for labelling rules alternatives.  For a rule with only a single alternative (no `|` in the rule), you're only adding unnecessary complexity.

Also, your Lexer defines a LOT of keywords.  If these values are keywords in ALL contexts, this is fine, but likely you'll run into situations where that "keyword" is valid in another context but isn't a keyword there.  (It also appears that many of these my only occur within strings, so this will just fall out of the refactoring suggested above)

Comment: Thank you. I'm leaning towards suggestion #2, though I am saddened by this, as one of the features I wanted to extend was the ability to decompile certain values, i.e.: DN and (even more importantly) Search Filters. In my tests, ANTLR *seems* to do a fantastic job on this point.  While I realize I can do this "after" the ANTLR processing phase in my package code manually, I had hoped to avoid this for a few different reasons.  Regardless, I sincerely appreciate your insight :)

Comment: Where parsing the string content is justifiably complex (something, perhaps like the distinguished name syntax), you may still find that ANTLR works well for it, and that those grammars will be simpler to manage than trying to roll it all together.